# BBC iPlayer paused when mute

Tags: safari, audio, macos

If I play a radio station through the BBC website, e.g. (I believe this is available worldwide):
http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/player/bbc_radio_two

When I mute the mac the playback pauses.  This doesn't seem to be a feature of the website and has started since updating to Yosemite (10.10).

Sounds pretty cool (like I say, doesn't seem to be something offered by the BBC) however I'm using this as a Alarm Clock, so load the webpage automatically a bit earlier than its needed and fade the sound in - now all the time checks are out (more than usual)!

Any ideas why this is happening and if anything can be done to turn it off.

Comment: I am not able to recreate this behaviour. Does the iPlayer timer (bottom-right) continue to tick up when muted? Are you muting using the Mac's mute keyboard key?

Comment: Thanks for checking - I don't see a timer (on the link given).  I'm using screen sharing so am actually turning the volume right down using the volume menu bar button